# how to use window.openDatabase to access the old db in phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I read the storage tutorial in PhoneGap dev page. 
In the example, it used the window.openDatabase twice. But the document says openDatabase return a new db object, I guess the goal of the example is to generate a new DB and then access it to get the data back. But then why did it create a new db object twice??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Populate the database 
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }

    // Query the database
    //
    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

    // Query the success callback
    //
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
  console.log("Returned rows = " + results.rows.length);
  // this will be true since it was a select statement and so rowsAffected was 0
  if (!results.rowsAffected) {
    console.log('No rows affected!');
    return false;
  }
  // for an insert statement, this property will return the ID of the last inserted row
  console.log("Last inserted row ID = " + results.insertId);
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(err) {
        console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000); //Why create a new DB again??
        db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);     //upon the success of create a database, jump to successCB
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Database</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783161/phonegap-storage-inserting-record-deletes-old-records

Did you get any solution

Answer (score 3):

The call to window.openDatabase will return a new db object but if you are asking for the same database name, in this case "Database", each db object will refer to the same physical database.

Answer (score 3):

Another good question is: Why would you want to open the database twice? Just do it once and store the returned object globally.

```
var db;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
}, false);
```